# How to open a current window in Full Screen Mode on button click in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-8, fullscreen

I have applied a jquery function in my MVC code for showing my current window in Full Screen Mode on button click. Here is the jquery for it :-

```js
function FullScreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || // alternative standard method
    (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) { // current working methods
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

I have called up this function on onclick event of  tag.
With this I am able to open my window on button click in full screen mode on Chrome and Mozilla and also come out of the full screen mode on pressing ESC key. But in IE8 when i click on the button nothing happens. How can i make this function to work for IE8. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a browser supports the Full Screen API (Chrome, FX10, Safari 6, Opera 12.1) then you can use it.

If it doesn't (for instance IE8) then you shouldn't be able to mimic it for security reasons: if I can create a page that runs full screen without notifying the user first I could then mimic OS interface elements that ask for passwords and the like.

Here is an excellent example of [how a phishing scam might work](http://feross.org/html5-fullscreen-api-attack/).

This security reason is why the WebKit implementation disables keyboard input.

IE used to support chrome-less pop-up windows, but this was [removed as a security bug in IE6](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/490708).

For instance you could try sending the F11 key:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.SendKeys("{F11}");
```

But that shouldn't get allowed in an internet context (it might in a trusted domain, depending on user settings).

IE10 runs full screen (by default) anyway, so still doesn't support this API.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, IE8 does not support Full Screen API yet. [Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/) is a good article about using Full Screen API. It also points that Internet Explorer does not have Full Screen API support.

> There’s no support in Internet Explorer or Opera yet, but I would
>   suggest you use the ‘ms’ and ‘o’ prefixes for future proofing.

Comment: I disagree - it's a bad idea to 'future proof' by guessing future prefixes, as you won't know the details of the implementation.